# How to include a Font Awesome icon in React's render()

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

Whenever I try to use a Font Awesome icon in React's `render()`, it isn't displayed on the resulting web page although it works in normal HTML.

```
render: function() {
    return <div><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin">no spinner but why</i></div>;
}
```

Here is an live example: http://jsfiddle.net/pLWS3/

Where is the fault?

Comment: Note that some older answers refer to `react-fontawesome` which is v4, and some to the official `@fortawesome/fontawesome` component which supports v5.

Comment: And here is the current link to the react-fontawesome which supports version 5: https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome

Answer (score 62, accepted):

React uses the `className` attribute, like the DOM.

If you use the development build, and look at the console, there's a warning.  You can see this on the jsfiddle.

> Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?

Comment: is that possible to work reactjs 15.6 i added link index.html  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> but can't work

Answer (score 394):

If you are **new to React JS** and using **create-react-app cli** command to create the application, then run the following NPM command to include the latest version of font-awesome.

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

import font-awesome to your index.js file. Just add below line to your index.js file

```
import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

or

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

Don't forget to use **className** as attribute

```
 render: function() {
    return <div><i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin">no spinner but why</i></div>;
}
```

Comment: This is actually the answer that best clarifies the initial question.

Comment: Just want to note that with the **create-react-app** setup, you don't need to include `../node_modules/` in the path...  `import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';` works :)

Comment: But in this way when we add icons like <i className="far fa-heart"></i> it doesn't render. But if we add <i className="fa fa-heart"></i> it renders. Why's that ?

Comment: @ThidasaParanavitharana using `<i className="far fa-heart"></i>` only works with font-awesome v5. This solution installs font-awesome v4

Comment: Also when I use `<i className="fa fa-heart-o"> </i>` nothing shows up in fontawesome 4.7. Anyone knows why?

Comment: This solution is great, but it will only install Font Awesome version 4. If you need icons from version 5 or above, you will need to use react-fontawesome, or alternatively and more simply, directly load the version 5 fontawesome css from the <head> section of your index.html file.

Answer (score 53):

https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome

install fontawesome & react-fontawesome

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
```

then in your component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid'
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you really need this: `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular` as it is not being used from your example.

Comment: @gabeno hey nope, its just a example. This should just remember/show u that u can use the other one too. But thx for the hint, i should add a comment.

Comment: Great! just need to modify this `import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'` FontAwesomeIcon is not default export anymore.

Answer (score 42):

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

in index.js

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
```

then use icons like below :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Like extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return <i className="fas fa-heart"></i>;
  }
}

export default Like;
```

Comment: This is the exact answer i wanted. Thank you!

Comment: That's what I'm looking for... Thank you men !

Comment: Thanks this is the easiest method

Comment: This no longer seems to work. Perhaps because of font awesome version 6.

Answer (score 39):

You can also use the `react-fontawesome` icon library. Here's the link: [react-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome)

From the NPM page, just install via npm:

```
npm install --save react-fontawesome
```

Require the module:

```
var FontAwesome = require('react-fontawesome');
```

And finally, use the `<FontAwesome />` component and pass in attributes to specify icon and styling:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <FontAwesome
        className='super-crazy-colors'
        name='rocket'
        size='2x'
        spin
        style={{ textShadow: '0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)' }}
      />
    );
  }
});
```

Don't forget to add the font-awesome CSS to index.html:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Comment: Don't forget to add the Font Awesome css to your index too: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
`

Comment: do you still need to include a cdn if you install it via npm?

Comment: I did. I might have misconfigured something else though.

Comment: @Amituuush "Installing" FA via NPM (for now) does not put it where it needs to be. You must always make sure to copy it to your corresponding `public` folder and add the stylesheet with the correct `src` manually.

Comment: New CDN link:
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Author of react-fontawesome here. You will need to include the styles/fonts in your application somehow, either with a CDN version or using something like WebPack or just linking to downloaded versions. The goal with this library was to not force a tool on you like WebPack

Comment: @guya in the link shared, there is some character between '-' and 'a' in "font-awesome.min.css"... Causes the link to break.

Comment: This answer is a copy of the actual npm package, with an addition of 1.5 sentences.

Answer (score 23):

The simplest solution is:

Install:

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Import:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faThumbsUp } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

Use:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faThumbsUp }/>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
npm install --save font-awesome

import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

then

```
<i className="fa fa-shopping-cart" style={{fontSize:24}}></i>  
        <span className="badge badge-danger" style={{position:"absolute", right:5, top:5}}>number of items in cart</span>
```

Answer (score 10):

In case you are looking to include the font awesome library without having to do module imports and npm installs, put this in the head section of your React *index.html* page:

***public/index.html*** (in head section)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
```

Then in your component (such as App.js) just use standard font awesome class convention. Just remember to use className instead of class:

`<button className='btn'><i className='fa fa-home'></i></button>`

Comment: tried this, not working!

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I found react-fontawesome to be unwieldy because of the way it requires each icon to be individually imported. If you would like to use Font Awesome version 5 with React without using react-fontawsome, you can do it as follows:

- Download the fontawesome free package from font awesome themselves here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself
- Create a directory 'fontawesome' in the 'public' directory of your react app.
- Copy the 'css' and 'webfonts' directories from the downloaded zip into this folder.
- Add the following line to the 'head' tag of your 'index.html' file:

```html
<link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You can now use Font Awesome icons in the usual way:

```html
<i className="fas fa-globe-europe"></i>
```

Answer (score 6):

as 'Praveen M P' said you can install font-awesome as a package. if you have yarn you can run:

```
 yarn add font-awesome
```

If you don't have yarn do as Praveen said and do:

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

this will add the package to your projects dependencies and install the package in your node_modules folder. in your App.js file add

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to install the package first.

```
npm install --save react-fontawesome
```

OR

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Don't forget to use `className` instead of `class`.

Later on you need to import them in the file where you wanna use them.

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
```

or

```
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
```

Answer (score 6):

After struggling with this for a while I came up with this procedure (based on Font Awesome's documentation [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react#how)):

As stated, you'll have to install **fontawesome**, **react-fontawesome** and **fontawesome icons library**:

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

and then import everything to your React app:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faStroopwafel } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faStroopwafel)
```

Here comes the tricky part:

To change or add icons, you'll have to find the available icons in your node modules library, 
i.e.

```
<your_project_path>\node_modules\@fortawesome\free-solid-svg-icons
```

Each icon has two relevant files: .js and .d.ts, and the file name indicates the import phrase (pretty obvious...), so adding **angry**, **gem** and **check-mark** icons looks like this:

```
import { faStroopwafel, faAngry, faGem, faCheckCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faStroopwafel, faAngry, faGem, faCheckCircle)
```

To use the icons in your React js code, use:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon=icon_name/>
```

The icon name can be found in the relevant icon's .js file:

e.g. for **faCheckCircle** look inside **faCheckCircle.js** for '**iconName**' variable:

```
...
var iconName = 'check-circle'; 
...
```

and the React code should look like this:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon=check-circle/>
```

Goodluck!

Comment: why aren't you mentioning where in the react app you place library.add(faStroopwafel)

Answer (score 5):

Alexander's answer from above really helped me out!

I was trying to get social accounts icons in the footer of my app I created with ReactJS so that I could easily add a hover state to them while also having them link my social accounts. This is what I ended up having to do:

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands
```

Then at the top of my footer component I included this:

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles/Footer.css';
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {faTwitter, faLinkedin, faGithub} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands';
```

My component then looked like this:

```
<a href='https://github.com/yourusernamehere'>
  <FontAwesomeIcon className ='font-awesome' icon={faGithub} />
</a>
```

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I was experienced this case; I need the react/redux site that should be working perfectly in production.

but there was a 'strict mode'; Shouldn't lunch it with these commands.

```
yarn global add serve
serve -s build
```

Should working with only click the build/index.html file.
When I used fontawesome with npm font-awesome, it was working in development mode but not working in the 'strict mode'.

Here is my solution:

```
public/css/font-awesome.min.css
public/fonts/font-awesome.eot 
*** other different types of files(4) ***
*** I copied these files for node_module/font-awesome ***
*** after copied then can delete the font-awesome from package.json ***
```

in public/index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

After all of above steps, the fontawesome works NICELY!!!

Answer (score 2):

If someone wants to do it via the Official documentation. Here is how I did and what I understood.

1. Install the library as mentioned on font awesome page using npm or yarn for example in general I used these

```
  npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
  npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
  npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

2. You need two import library from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' if you want to use in general or globally, it provides the access to the icons everywhere in your project.

```
  import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
```

3. To use the icons you need to import them based on the npm or yarn library you have installed. I would recommend importing this in App.js where it will be easily visible. Like If I was using a free-tier shopping cart icon and it was solid you can import like below (if you are not sure if its solid, regular, etc or what library just click on the icon it will list out the different versions and based on the icon you like you can import the library for react).

```
  import { faShoppingCart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

- for adding the icon name I would recommend writing the import statement and library and then precede with `fa` and start typing the name it will auto-recommend as soon as you type (checked in VSCode) which will make it less complicated to find.

4. You need to add the icons in the library for making it accessible globally in your project separated by a comma

```
library.add( faCheckSquare, faAmbulance, faShoppingCart);
```

5. After which you can import the following component

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
```

and use it like below wherever you need the icon. For the name, it's the same as listed on the style class on the FontAwesome site, for the icons. eg: shopping cart is listed as shopping-cart

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="shopping-cart" />
```

It should work now after this.

Answer (score 2):

you can install react-icons using:
**npm i react-icons**
then import the fontawesome icons you want, for example:

```
import { FaHome } from "react-icons/fa"
```

then add it wherever you want:

```
<FaHome />
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [react icons](http://gorangajic.github.io/react-icons/index.html) pretty dope and worked well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was following the documentation for `react-fontawesome` package, but they aren't clear about how to call the icon when setting the icons into the library

this is was what I was doing:

> App.js file

```
import {faCoffee} from "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons";
library.add(faSearch, faFileSearch, faCoffee);
```

> Component file

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={"coffee"} />
```

But I was getting this error

[image]
Then I added the alias when passing the icon prop like:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fal", "coffee"]} />
```

And it is working, you can find the prefix value in the icon.js file, in my case was: faCoffee.js

Comment: For the first option, you should be doing:
`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />`

Answer (score 1):

### For Font Awesome v6.x.x

Fontawesome provides [three ways](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons#alternative-ways-to-add-icons) to use its icons.

After considering ease of usage and bundle size. The below method looks best.

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core

# free icons styles
yarn add @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
yarn add @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons

yarn add @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@latest
```

import icons that you want.

```
import { faClipboard } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faClipboard as farClipboard } from "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons";
```

> Note: if you need a Solid icon you need to import it from `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons` and if you need a Regular icon you need to import it from `@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons`

Prefix regular icons with `far` instead of `fa` as a convention

Usage:

```
  <p>
    This is a free Solid Icon <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClipboard} />
  </p>
  <p>
    This is a free Regular Icon <FontAwesomeIcon icon={farClipboard} />
  </p>
```

Note:
As you [search for icons](https://fontawesome.com/icons/clipboard?s=solid&f=classic) in Fontawesome documentation and copy the code you will get something as below. However, you need to change the icon prop to the above-mentioned value for the icon to display.

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-clipboard" />
```

Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-cannon-ffx478?file=/src/App.js) for the above-mentioned snippets.

Refer to [official Docs](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/) for more info.

---

PS: You can only use Free Solid, and Free Regular icons under the free plan.

Here is [the list](https://fontawesome.com/search?o=r&m=free&s=solid) of icons that are available under free plan.