# how to have webpack include font awesome woff files in a react based chrome extension?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, webpack, font-awesome, woff

I'm developing a React.js based chrome extension where all assets are bundled with webpack. On development (with `webpack-dev-server`), I successfully managed to have Chrome load `.woff` files from `localhost:3000`. This is part of the loaders of my development webpack config:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: /node_modules/,
    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader'
  }
```

The chrome extension for development has the following privileges (among others):

`font-src 'self' http://localhost:3000 https://localhost:3000;`

This works fine, I can use [react-fa](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-fa) to use font-awesome like so:

`<Icon name="eye" size="2x" />`

However, as soon as I stop using webpack-dev-server, and build to an actual bundle to be imported as a Google chrome extension (**with the same loaders)**, I start seeing the following errors in my console:

```
GET chrome-extension://jboakcijpodokbkfeooiffmbbmlfobnl/926c93d201fe51c8f351e858468980c3.woff2 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
?brudy:1

GET chrome-extension://jboakcijpodokbkfeooiffmbbmlfobnl/891e3f340c1126b4c7c142e5f6e86816.woff net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
?brudy:1

GET chrome-extension://jboakcijpodokbkfeooiffmbbmlfobnl/fb650aaf10736ffb9c4173079616bf01.ttf net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

My chrome extension's manifest permissions are set appropriately, I believe:

`font-src 'self';`

But for some reason the `.woff2` file does not seem to be within the bundle, at least not at that address. I checked the bundle/build folder and found the file at `/build/js/926c93d201fe51c8f351e858468980c3.woff2`.

How would I make sure that the file is indeed accessible at the address `chrome-extension://jboakcijpodokbkfeooiffmbbmlfobnl/926c93d201fe51c8f351e858468980c3.woff2`?

Comment: Maybe you need to add your font path to `web_accessible_resources` if you want it is accessible by other web pages. Not much clear about your question sorry.

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: @Tom did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is a hacky way around, so to include the fontawesome on your react chrome extension app first install [fontawesome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44985218/9854303) then build the react app i.e., `yarn build` after that you will see all the static media files in your `build/static/media/` directory either copy the name of each file into your `/public/manifest.json` for example like

```
  "web_accessible_resources":[
    "/static/css/content.css",
    "/static/media/fontawesome-webfont.674f50d2.eot",
    "/static/media/fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d.svg",
    "/static/media/fontawesome-webfont.b06871f2.ttf",
    "/static/media/fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505.woff2",
    "/static/media/fontawesome-webfont.fee66e71.woff"
  ],
```

or you can copy the name of media files from `/build/asset-manifest.json` to `/public/manifest.json`, then again run `yarn build`, now all the static media files will be added into `/build/manifest.json` and then upload the build files to
`chrome://extensions/`.
This was the solution I found out after hours.