# fontawesome is not working with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

I'm trying to use FontAwesome with React.js but it is not working.

In `Button.js` I have:

```
import React from "react";
import FontAwesome from "react-fontawesome";
const Button = () => {
   return <FontAwesome name="rocket" />;
};
export default Button;
```

and in `index.html` I included the FontAwesome CDN: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check this may be it will solve you issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116591/how-to-include-a-font-awesome-icon-in-reacts-render

Answer (score 0):

There's not a problem with `react-fontawesome` package, but the problem is in your react code, you are write return FontAwesome component outside of function, your react apps will not work.

Look this Button component with font-awesome, don't forget for import React in Button.js, and ofcourse import font-awesome css in your index.html.

```
import React from "react";
import FontAwesome from "react-fontawesome";
const Button = () => {
    return <FontAwesome name="rocket" />;
};
export default Button;
```

Then you just need to import Button from Button.js

```
...
import Button from "./Button";

...
<Button />
...
```

Comment: actually, I did all this stuff. I just did not write that down! Now i have edited my answer!