# FontAwesome Icons in Input Placeholder using React

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I'm using React for creating an app and I want to use FontAwesome icons for including them into the input placeholder, so that it would look like

```
<input type="text" placeholder="[here should be the user icon] Username" />
```

How can I do that? I've used `"&#xF007; Username"` and it shows only a square instead of an icon. Maybe I forgot something?

Comment: Did you set fontawesome as the font family of the input? I’ve never used fontawesome for a placeholder, but if you’re seeing a square instead of an icon, it usually means that you aren’t using the fontawesome font, and whatever font you are using doesn’t have that character in it.

Comment: I've installed react-fontawesome. Maybe I declared font-family: FontAwesome in a wrong way? Or should I import font awesome in my scss?

Comment: have you put styles for [`::placeholder`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/) to use font awesome?

Comment: Yep. I've put styles for ::placeholder. But how should I import font-awesome itself to use it at a font-family?

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder

Answer (score 2):

Try including your icon as an `InputAddon` rather than forcing it into your placeholder. You can do this a few ways. I would suggest the two listed below.

**Approach 1: Bootstrap**

You can install bootstrap and use the `input-group-prepend` or `input-group-append` classes and place your icon there.

Example:

```
    import { FaUserAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="input-group mb-3">
          <div className="input-group-prepend">
            <i className="classes you have"><FaUserAlt /></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
       </div>
     )
  }
```

This will require you to install `bootstrap` and `react-icons`. The `bootstrap` install will allow you to use those `classNames` and the `react-icons` install will allow you to use `<FaUserAlt />` as a component rather than going through CSS. To install `bootstrap` use: `npm i bootstrap`. To install `react-icons` use : `npm i react-icons`.

**Approach 2: Reactstrap**

You can use `reactstrap` which is essentially Bootstrap for react. This will require you to install both `reactstrap`, `react-icons`, and `bootstrap` like so: `npm i reactstrap bootstrap react-icons`.

Example: From `reactstrap` documentation (slightly altered)

```
import React from 'react';
import { InputGroup, InputGroupText, InputGroupAddon, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { FaUserAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';
const Example = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <InputGroup>
        <Input placeholder="Username" />
        <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
          <FaUserAlt />
        </InputGroupAddon>
      </InputGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

**Alternative Approach**

You can simply do the above with CSS. I would go that route if you are only using this "icon placeholder" once. But, if you are consistently doing this throughout your app, I think it maybe worth it to look into the above two approaches.

Hope this helps anyone who comes across this.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who faces this issue:

This one worked for me: [How to include a Font Awesome icon in React's render()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116591/how-to-include-a-font-awesome-icon-in-reacts-render)

Instead of @fortawesome/react-fontawesome package, I used font-awesome package.

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

Now import font-awesome in your index.js file

```
import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

or

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

Then the code in question goes like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="&#xF007; Username" />
```

Just copy unicode of your desired icon from https://fontawesome.com and replace **F007** with it.

And style input tag with following:

```
font-family: FontAwesome;
```