# How to include font awesome in a .net core 2.2 react-redux project

Tags: .net, typescript, react-redux, font-awesome

So i created a new project with .net core 2.2 react-redux (typescript)
and i want to use font awesome.

how do i proceed ?

I have tried installing the npm package and putting in my boot-client.tsx filebut it does not work

import '../../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';

Comment: How do you created React project with .Net core using typescript? Today i created a project but that is not showing .ts or .tsx files

Answer (score 0):

[I think this can solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116591/how-to-include-a-font-awesome-icon-in-reacts-render)

Or, I use this way in my project: Look at typical project structure in Redux (projects on github e.g.), You can make in 'common' folder used icon with font-awesome, and import this from files.